# Git sync branch from fork

Tags: git

I understand how to sync a forked repo: set the upstream of my fork then run `git fetch upstream && git checkout master && git merge upstream/master`. What I've having trouble with is syncing a branch from another persons fork.

Suppose there's a repository `org/foo` with a commit, `Z`. Bob makes a fork, `bob/foo`. Jane also makes a fork, `jane/foo`. Now, Bob makes a feature branch `bob/foo:feature-a`, commits `A` and publishes this branch. Jane then checks out `bob/foo:feature-a` and creates a new branch off it, `jane/foo:feature-b` (jane has two branches locally now). Next, Bob pushes a new commit, `A'` and Jane wants to rebase `feature-b` on the latest commit of `feature-a`. How does she do it?

Hopefully this diagram is helpful

```
Time               0   1    2       3     4      5

bob/foo:feature-a      A - - - - - -A'
                     /  \
org/foo            Z     \
                          \
jane/foo:feature-b          A - B         magic  A - A' - B
```

How does Jane sync her local checkout of `bob/foo:feature-a` at `t=4` to include commit `A'` so that she can rebase commit `B` onto it?

Comment: Can you describe how Bob and Jane ceate their fork ? Do they both fork `org/foo` ? does Jane fork `bob/foo` ?

Comment: they both fork from `org/foo`

Answer (score 0):

It's said in your scenario, I will just highlight it: Bob has pushed commit `A` and a branch named `feature-a` to `org/foo` (implied with "publishes branch `feature-a`")

So Jane actually fetched commit `A` and `feature-a` from central repo `org/foo`.

Once Bob has added commit `A'`, *and published it to `org/foo`*, Jane will be able to fetch it from `org/foo` :

```
# from Jane's fork :
git checkout feature-b
git fetch origin             # will fetch commit A' as part of branch feature-a
git rebase origin/feature-a  # rebase on top of Bob's work
```